# Visualstudio makefile (NMAKE)

Tags: windows, makefile

I am in need to create a makefile for visual studio. however the documentation for this on Microsoft websites is very gently speaking: lousy. Googling doesn't help either. Could somebody paste a link or simple tutorial on how to create such makefile (for example compiling one program from two cpp files). Also mentioning if include files like in GNU are possible to use (and how to import them in makefile). Or how can i echo something in makefile.

I have seen [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/60340) but is of not much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). It's a cross platform build system. I have used it to generate project and solution files for VS 2010, however there is [NMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#gen:NMakeMakefiles)  generator also.

This video should get you started - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9sKd8f0kFo.